# ubuntu server disk space usage

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I have an Ubuntu server.my Mysql service stopped and it did not start.
I found out that my free disk space is very low.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1      32G   31G     0 100% /
none                  497M  312K  497M   1% /dev
none                  501M     0  501M   0% /dev/shm
none                  501M  252K  501M   1% /var/run
none                  501M     0  501M   0% /var/lock
none                  501M     0  501M   0% /lib/init/rw
```

I saw

> /dev/cciss/c0d0p1

It fills all of my servers disk space.
I try

> umount /dev/cciss/c0d0p1

but device was busy.
I looked for process that use c0d0p1
here is result of

> fuser -m /dev/cciss/c0d0p1
>
> /dev/cciss/c0d0p1:       1rce     2rc     3rc     4rc     5rc     6rc 
>   7rc     8rc     9rc    10rc    11rc    12rc    13rc    14rc    16rc
>   17rc    18rc    19rc    20rc    21rc    22rc    23rc    24rc    25rc
>   26rc    27rc    28rc    29rc    30rc    31rc    34rc    35rc    36rc
>   37rc    38rc    39rc    40rc    41rc    45rc    46rc    49rc    50rc
>   51rc    52rc    53rc    54rc    55rc    56rc    57rc   189rc   192rc
>   193rc   215rc   216rc   217rc   260rce   262rce   326rce   332rce
>   376rc   402rc   481rce   530rce   548rce   588rc   589rc   590rc
>   591rc   592rc   593rc   594rc   595rc   596rc   597rc   598rc   599rc 
>   600rc   601rc   602rc   603rc   604rc   605rc   610re   614re   618re 
>   619re   622re   623rce   629rce   630rce   656rce   673rce   677re
>   682re   697re   713rce   727rce   728rce   729rce   730rce   731rce
>   746re   775rce   776e   777e   778e   779e   780e   781e   782rc
>   784rce   786rce   853rce   868rce

Comment: Like I said in the question you posted four hours ago: You should consider accepting some answers to your questions before asking any more.

Comment: You don't need a Q&A site you need some basic education on the tools you have. As it is your level of understanding is way below that which we would need to help you.

Comment: This is actually a well-asked question.  It clearly explains what the problem is and what he's already tried, no matter how *wrong* it may be.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to unmount your root partition, this is not a good idea. Instead you should free up space on that disk. You can start by looking for obsolete files in your /var/log folder and the home folders for all your users. Also do not forget to clean out /tmp.

Comment: If [your earlier question](http://serverfault.com/q/352184/26130) is any clue, `/var/spool/mail` might be a good place to look.

Answer (score 2):

It tells you that the root file system `/` is used by *every* process and that you can't unmount it in a running system. Why would you anyway? You have to delete files on the disk, but it's not necessary to unmount it for this purpose.

In other words, `/dev/cciss/c0d0p1` *is* your servers' only disk space and is not what filled it - if you unmount it, you have no space at all, neither full nor empty.

Answer (score 2):

Clear up some disk space and try installing [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) utility. It's available from repositories on some systems. If not, compile it manually. Just run this utility and in some period of time (maybe 20 min for your 30G disk) you will get aware of all directories sorted by their disk usage. Thus, you will be able to find out where the problem is. Sometimes results are very surprising, as you may find some outdated backups, etc. I'd recommend to start it in screen.